# Rendering a partial with jQuery within Users model

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am relatively new to Rails, and so I am not sure if I am correctly routing/structuring my controller and view.

Simply, I am just trying to use tabs within the user/show.html.erb page to render partial in the content area below it with jQuery.

However, when I refresh the page with my code, I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `userprofile_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8c181e9ff0>:0x007f8c171662a0>
```

My app>views>users>show.html.erb :

```
<div id="profile-box">
<ul class="profile-tabs">
        <%= link_to "<li class=\"tab selected\">Current</li>".html_safe, userprofile_path, remote: true %>
        <%= link_to "<li class=\"tab\">Offers</li>".html_safe, userprofile_path, remote: true %>
        <%= link_to "<li class=\"tab\">Sales</li>".html_safe, userprofile_path, remote: true %> 
    </ul>

<div id="profile-content">

</div>
</div>
```

My app>controllers>users_controller.rb :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def userprofile
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end

end
```

My app>assets>javascripts>userprofile.js :

```
$(function() {
        $("li.tab").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("li.tab").removeClass("selected");
          $(this).addClass("selected");
          $("#profile-content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 
"users/offers")%>");
        });
    });
```

I am also using Devise, so here is my routes.rb file:

```
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}

resources :users
```

Since I am new to Rails, I am not sure if its an issue with bad or missing code, the files not being named correctly, if I need a new file somewhere to make it work, or what exactly it is.

If anyone could point me in the right direction in terms of the code I need and the structure of the app, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: what do your routes look like ? did you use `resources :users` ?

Comment: I just updated the question to include my routes file. I am using Devise too, so is that causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare a route before using an action... `resources` only creates standard restful routes, you have to add a custom one in this case. Example :

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get :userprofile # it would create a helper like userprofile_users_path
  end
end
```

see [the rails guides on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more info.

As a side note, if your action concerns only one user, use `member` instead of `collection`

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand the theory behind this: Is this because these actions are not part of the 7 standard RESTful actions, and thus must be manually routed?

Comment: yes, exactly. Resources creates 7 routes to your 7 actions. For other actions you have to declare routes manually.

Answer (score 1):

For adding `userprofile_path` route, do this:

```
devise_for :users, :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'} do
   match '/profile', :to => 'users#userprofile', :as => 'userprofile'
end
```

Comment: So the idea here is to manually route the action to the users controller as opposed to the Devise controller?

Comment: Yes, since you already declared `resources :users`, I had to offer this. Primarily, I route the action with the RegistrationController of Devise itself. Works like charm.